# Flink DataSet Tuple Values not coming as expected

Tags: apache-flink

I have a `Dataset<Tuple3<String,String,Double>> values` which has the following data:

```
<Vijaya,Chocolate,5>
<Vijaya,Chips,10>
<Rahul,Chocolate,2>
<Rahul,Chips,8>
```

I want the `DataSet<Tuple5<String,String,Double,String,Double>> values1`as following:

```
<Vijaya,Chocolate,5,Chips,10>
<Rahul,Chocolate,2,Chips,8>
```

My code looks like following:

```
DataSet<Tuple5<String, String, Double, String, Double>> values1 = values.fullOuterJoin(values)
    .where(0)
    .equalTo(0)
    .with(
        new JoinFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Tuple5<String, String, Double, String, Double>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Tuple5<String, String, Double, String, Double> join(Tuple3<String, String, Double> first, Tuple3<String, String, Double> second) {
                return new Tuple5<String, String, Double, String, Double>(first.f0, first.f1, first.f2, second.f1, second.f2);
            }
        })
    .distinct(1, 3)
    .distinct(1);
```

In the above  code I tried doing self join.I want the output in that particular format but I am unable to get it.
How to do this?
Please help.

Comment: Any source code? What have you tried, that doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want the output to have the same item repeated, you can use a flat-join, in which you can output only those records that have the value in the 2nd position not equal to the value in the 4th position. Also, if you want only "chocolate" in the 2nd position, that can also be checked inside the FlatJoinFunction. Please find below the link to Flink's documentation about Flat-join.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#join-with-flat-join-function

Approach using GroupReduceFunction:

```
     values
    .groupBy(0)
    .reduceGroup(new GroupReduceFunction<Tuple3<String,String,Double>, Tuple2<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Iterable<Tuple3<String,String,Double>> in, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> out) {

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            String name = null;

            for (Tuple3<String,String,Double> item : in) {          

                name = item.f0;
                output.append(item.f1+","+item.f2+",");         

            }

            out.collect(new Tuple2<String, String>(name,output.toString())); 

        }
    });
```

Comment: with distinct(0) I get the following output:
`(Vijaya,Chocolate,5,Chocolate,5)` which doesnot comes up as required output.

Comment: I tried but in vain. Can you please explain it a bit.

Comment: In the above said method there is a redundancy. The output is:

`(Vijaya,Chocolate,5,Chips,10)
(Vijaya,Chips,10,Chocolate,5)`

This i don't want. I want only one row without redundancy.  What if someday i have 3 rows with the third row (Vijaya,dolls,6). Still there would be redundancy. The output won't be coming like `(Vijaya,Chocolate,5,Chips,10,Dolls,6)`

Comment: That is why I have mentioned that 'if you want only "chocolate" in the 2nd position, that can also be checked inside the FlatJoinFunction'

Comment: Sir what if a third person named Rohit is added having like:

(Rohit,Chips,8)

So after joining the whole data using FlatJoinFunction
will i get like the following:
`(Rohit,Null,Null,Chips,8)`

Comment: What is the result that you want in that case? (Rohit,Chips,8) or (Rohit,Chocolate,0,Chips,8) or (Rohit,Null,Null,Chips,8) ?

Comment: I want the third option as my first priority as (Rohit,Null,Null,Chips,8) . Even if that is not possibble the second priority would the second one (Rohit,Chocolate,0,Chips,8).

Comment: So the order of the items in the result is important? It should be (Rohit,null,null,Chips,8), not (Rohit,Chips,8,null,null)?

Comment: either case is fine..

Actually I tried with distinct too but in vain.
the table may have the following structure:
`(Vijaya, Chocolate, 5)
(Vijaya,Chips,8)
(Rahul,Chips,10)
(Rohit,Chocolate,8)`
Result must be:
`(Vijaya,Chocolate,5,Chips,8)
(Rahul,null,null,Chips,10)
(Rohit,Chocolate,8,null,null)`

Comment: To the above the Row `(Rahul,Chips,10,null,null)` is also acceptable.

Comment: Also, if there is another input like (Vijaya,dolls,6), you want the result to be (Vijaya,Chocolate,5,Chips,10,Dolls,6)?

Comment: Yes sir that would be great.

Comment: So the number of fields in the output tuple can vary depending on the number of items (chocolate,dolls or chips or something else) for the same person. Is it ok to have a comma separated String as the output? Eg: Tuple2<String,String>(Vijaya,"Chocolate,5,Chips,10,Dolls,6")?

Comment: Yes comma separated  String would do as flink only supports 25 tuples at maximum. Like it should be a permanent solution without looking at number of data.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an approach using GroupReduce. You will not get the null values in this. But the result will have all valid values.

Comment: Thank you so much. This actually worked.Thanks a lot again.